# Error using KFold (from sklearn.model_selection import KFold)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I am getting an error  while using from sklearn.model_selection import KFold in my jupyter  notebook.

The error says "No module named 'sklearn.model_selection'". When I printed

```
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

I got the version to be 0.17.1.

Can anyone help me understand what is the problem?

Comment: You don't happen to have a file named 'sklearn.py' somewhere in the directory you're running this code, do you?

Comment: Also, 0.17 is an old version. Try upgrading to the latest version and see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Under version `0.17.1` `KFold` is found under `sklearn.cross_validation`. Only in versions >= `0.19` can `KFold` be found under `sklearn.model_selection`

So you need to change your import to:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
```

See [API](http://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/classes.html) for version `0.17`

Comment: Nope, it was available in `model_selection` since version 0.18. But in that time, `cross_validation` also existed as a deprecated version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better this way:

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).